# Browser search (Ctrl+F) for Slickgrid column header is giving focus on column header but column data is out of alignment

Tags: javascript, jquery, slickgrid

When I try to search in the page, pressing CTRL+F or using browser find for slickgrid column which is out of the viewport (not scrolled into view), It would focus on column header but column data is not getting scrolled and slickgrid data is missing alignment with column header. Any help would be highly appreciated!! please find attached image:

[image]

Comment: You didn't attach the image.

Comment: I hope you see image now!

Comment: Maybe you are missing a td or something....

Comment: this is happening only when user browser search (CTRL+F) to find slickgrid column header otherwise it looks good.